# Having trouble installing and loading tidyverse- No DIB package

Tags: dataset

after a fresh (Control panel, Windows 7) uninstall, then re-install of Rstudio, I have tried to install and load tidyverse.  I get the following message, seemingly because the package DBI is missing:

> install.packages("tidyverse")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jshea/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/tidyverse_1.1.1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 41994 bytes (41 KB)
>   downloaded 41 KB
>   package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\jshea\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpmoPd5V\downloaded_packages

> library(tidyverse)
>   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘DBI’
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’

Earlier this morning, when I did this the first time, the system seemed to download all the packages except there was some kind of error associated with DBI- I think a database package.  Even uninstalling and deleting obvious remnants of Rstudio does not seem to give me a clean base to fix this.  What can I do?

Comment: welcome to data science SE! If you read the error message carefully you will see that you are missing the `DBI` package. This has nothing to do with RStudio.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you do not have a dependency installed which `tidyverse` needs to run correctly.

Usually dependencies install with the package, but at times you need to coerce them to do so, so I usually install with the coercion for all packages.

```
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE)
```

In this case, if that was the only error, or you installed in this manner and did not get `DBI`, then I would just install it directly:

```
install.packages("DBI", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Once you have done that, if you are still having problems, explicitly load DBI:

`require(DBI)` or `library(DBI)`

and you should be good to go.

If you have a problem still, comment and I will try to help you chase it down.

Comment: although in looking it does not seem to be needed to run `tidyverse`...odd!

Comment: no,,,I checked and it is needed by `tidyverse` and three of its dependencies too...

Comment: Thank you.  The steps of Install.packages("DBI", dependencies=TRUE) and library(DBI) seemed to do the trick.

Comment: for some reason it is not listed as a dependency for `tidyverse`, probably because its other dependencies depend on it...but it is necessary. Glad it is working!